# Vue - Return Promise in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, fetch, vue-component, es6-promise

I'm having a problem with a Vue JS. I'm looping over some "posts" from the WordPress Rest API, and I have to print the author of the post inside the v-for loop, for each post. The author assigned to a post, is only an ID, so I have to make a new call to the API, to get the author name based on the returned ID.

The issue i'm running into, is that when i call the function that's fetching the Author Name, it's constantly switching back and forth between all the users assigned to the posts in the posts object.

```
Vue.component('blog-posts', {
    props: {
        posts: {},
    },

    data() {
        return {
            userName: '',
        }
    },

    template: `
        <section class="entry" v-if="posts.length">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <article v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.index">
                    <h1><a :href="post.link">{{ post.title.rendered }}</a></h1>
                    <p v-html="post.content.rendered"></p>

                    // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                    <p v-if="getAuthor(post.author)">{{ userName }}</p>

                    <button type="submit" @click="deletePost(post)">Slet indlæg</button>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
    `,

    created() {
        // Of course it works if i put a constant user id in, but i need to parse in inside the loop.
        // this.getAuthor(2);
    },

    computed: {

    },

    methods: {
        deletePost: function(post) {
            let path = new wp.api.collections.Posts({
                id: post.id
            });

            Event.$emit('delete-post', path, post.id);
        },


        getAuthor(author) {
            let vm = this;

            let user = new wp.api.models.User({
                id: author,
            });

            return user.fetch().then(response => {
                vm.userName = response.name;
                // return true;
            });
        },

        // showAuthor(author) {
        //  let user = new wp.api.models.User({
        //      id: author
        //  });

        //  user.fetch().then(response => {
        //      this.userName = response.name;
        //      // return true;
        //  });
        // },
    },

});



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        wp: wp.api,
        message: 'Hello Vue',
        posts: [],
    },

    mounted() {
        let posts = new wp.api.collections.Posts();
        let response = posts.fetch().then(response => {
            this.posts = response;
        });

        Event.$on('post-added', (item) => {
            this.posts.unshift(item.attributes);
        });

        // Delete post
        Event.$on('delete-post', (item, id) => {
            this.posts.forEach((post, index) => {
                if ( post.id === id ) {
                    this.posts.splice(index, 1);
                    item.at(0).destroy();
                }
            });
        });
    },
});
```

I'm not entirely sure this is the best way to return the value of a function call.

Comment: _"it's constantly switching back and forth between all the users assigned to the posts in the posts object."_ What is the expected result of `this.posts.unshift(item.attributes)` and `this.posts.splice(index, 1)`?

Comment: How about creating a predefined object of id->authorname and use that for displaying author name.As this will make a single api call and use the values from objects later.

Comment: Your issue is that you are basically re-writing the `userName` for every single posts that is displayed in your component template. What you should do is actually to collect all the post authors and make a single call to the endpoint.

Comment: @guest271314 `this.posts.unshift` and `this,posts.splice` is just to add/delete posts on the frontend. I just included it to show the entire code.

Comment: @TobiasMadsen What do you mean by _"it's constantly switching back and forth between all the users assigned to the posts in the posts object"_?

Comment: @Terry ok, but how would you call the function, it seems like bad practice the way i do it right now.

Comment: @guest271314 as of now i have 2 test users, "vue" and "test". And with the above code, the `{{ userName }}` on the frontend is constantly switching back and forth between vue and test. on each posts in the v-for loop.

Comment: @TobiasMadsen Have not tried Vue.js. Perhaps another user can help more than can here. The use of `.unshift()` and `.splice()` within asynchronous code could be part of the issue.

Comment: @guest271314 `unshift()` and `splice()` is not really a part of the problem i have, it's only in the `blog-post` component i'm having issues, as it's the only place i'm using a function inside af v-for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your `blog-posts` component contains multiple blog posts, but they all share a single reference to the `username`. As the blog posts may be authored by different people, you will of course overwrite the `username` multiple times as you iterate through individual posts.

The best solution is actually to abstract individual blog post into its own atomic component, e.g., your `<blog-posts>` component is simply a container for multiple `<blog-post>`: schematically it should look like this:

```
└─ <blog-posts>
    ├─ <blog-post>
    ├─ <blog-post>
    ├─ <blog-post>
    ├─ <blog-post>
    └─ <blog-post>
```

You can use `:post="post"` so that you pass the entire `post` data into your atomic component:

```
// The `<blog-posts>` component is only a COLLECTION of `<blog-post>`
// So it is a "dumb" component in a sense
Vue.component('blog-posts', {
    props: {
        posts: {},
    },
    template: `
        <section class="entry" v-if="posts.length">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <blog-post v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.index" :post="post" />
            </div>
        </section>
    `
});
```

All post-related logic should be removed from the `<blog-posts>` collection component and be moved into the atomic `<blog-post>` component instead. Then, in your new `<blog-post>` component, you can:

- Handle all the templating needs of an individual post
- Handle individual post actions, such as post deletion
- Most importantly: use the `mounted()` lifecycle hook to perform the API call to fetch the username pertaining to that *individual* post

So, your atomic component code will look a bit like this:

```
// The `<blog-post>` component is atomic
// It contains all the information related to a SINGLE post
Vue.component('blog-post', {
    props: {
        post: {},
    },

    data() {
        // Each individual blog post stores its own username
        return {
            userName: '';
        }
    },

    template: `
        <article>
            <h1><a :href="post.link">{{ post.title.rendered }}</a></h1>
            <p v-html="post.content.rendered"></p>

            <p>{{ userName }}</p>

            <button type="submit" @click="deletePost(post)">Slet indlæg</button>
        </article>
    `,

    methods: {
        deletePost: function(post) {
            let path = new wp.api.collections.Posts({
                id: post.id
            });

            Event.$emit('delete-post', path, post.id);
        }
    },

    mounted: function() {
        // Fetch post author metadata when the `<blog-post>` component is mounted
        let user = new wp.api.models.User({
            id: author,
        });

        user.fetch().then(responsve => this.userName = response.name);
    }

});
```

Comment: Didn't really think about that, but I can see how it could work.
Although it seems like a big markup change, just because of a single function call. There isn't any alternatives, to return a value from a Promise inside a v-for directive, or just any other function call.

Comment: @TobiasMadsen I would not call it a big markup change, because the change is necessary: of course, you can even make do without the `<blog-posts>` collection and simply do `v-for` in the app template directly ;) however, you need to make your blog post atomic so that each blog post component will store its own state (e.g. its own author name). That responsibility should not lie in a consuming collection component.

Comment: Actually makes alot of sense, much appreciated for the well explained comment :)
I just didn't think about splitting it into smaller bits, to handle the data, as my only problem was that single function call. I was losing my mind over it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Everything on the display side should be reactive. You should not be calling a method, any method, in the v-if of a template. You don't know/shouldn't care when the template is rendered.

Try defining a `data` to hold your author details, then calling `getAuthor()` from a created hook.

Comment: How do you mean with the data object?
I have this right now in the component:

`data() {
        return {
            userName: '',
        }
    },`